# How to choose only one row at a time in html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to choose only one row at a time from html table... Im using php,html and javascript.. if i choose one row means that the value only show in alert box at a time using javascript.. 
 I wrote some js coding but it shows all the row values one by one in alertbox.. Please anyone help for me..

My html code:

```html
<table BORDER="5">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="10">
                           
                            
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date & Time</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Source</th>
                        <th>Destination</th>
                        <th>Ride Type</th>
                        <th>Vehicle Type</th>
                        <th>Plate No.</th>
                        <th>Distance</th>
               </tr>
                     <?php $search_data = "";?>
                    <tbody id="table"style="cursor:pointer"onclick="found(this);">
                    <tr id="choose">
                    
                            <?php echo $search_data; ?>
                            
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                      
                </table>
```

My javascript:

```js
function found(row) {
     //alert("hai");
     var table=document.getElementById("table");
     var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
     for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
     alert(cells[i].innerHTML);
}
     
    }
```

My php code:
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($firstattempt)) 
            {

```
        $search_data = "";
       $search_data .= "<tr>";
            $search_data .= "<td>{$data["DATE"]} & {$data["START_TIME"]}</td>";
            $search_data .= "<td>{$data["NAME"]}</td>";             
            $search_data .= "<td>{$data["START_FROM"]}</td>";
            $search_data .= "<td>{$data["END_TO"]}</td>";
            $search_data .= "<td>{$data["RIDER_FLAG"]}</td>";
            $search_data .= "<td>{$data["VEHICLE_TYPE"]}</td>";
            $search_data .= "<td>{$data["PLATE_NO"]}</td>";
            $search_data .= "<td>{$distance} Km</td>";

            $search_data .= "</tr>";
            echo $search_data;

  }
```

My output :
[image: output]

Comment: read the foreach document .. it might help you a lot

Comment: how you are choosing rows?

Comment: this will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044257/javascript-to-add-table-row-onclick-events  just init your table on window load

Answer (score 0):

```js
function found(row) {
     //alert("hai");
     var table=document.getElementById("table");
     var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
     for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
     alert(cells[i].innerHTML);
}
     
    }
```

The for loop is what's showing all the tr's 1 by 1. If you want to only alert 1, remove the for loop and just use the alert sentence, and place a number instead of an i

```
alert(cells[0].innerHTML);
```

Would show the first element for example.

Comment: i had confuse, could you alter my code send.. Please

Answer (score 0):

try below js:

```
function fount(row) {
    var tr = row.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (var i = 0; i< tr.length; i++) {
        tr[i].onclick = function() {
            alert(this.innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to add yes/no button in this alertbox

Comment: change alert to confirm